# Updating WordPress with SSH (Cent OS)

Tags: linux, wordpress, ssh, ftp

I am new to SSH and Linux and I hope someone can help. I am working on a site with a dedicated server (VPS) and I am also working with WordPress. I used SSH to log into the site's files with Cyberduck (I've also used FileZilla successfully) and install WordPress on the server.

The problem I'm having now is that I can't edit or add any plugins or files on WordPress because WordPress doesn't have access to the site's FTP which is standard. It asks for credentials and when I attempt to enter them into the WordPress dashboard, it doesn't work. There is an option for FTP and there is an option for FTPS (SSL). I know these are different than SSH but I tried the SSH credentials anyway and obviously they didn't work.

I then logged into the SSH through Mac Terminal and did the instructions here:

```
1. Login as root through SSH.

2. Next add the user account you want using the 'useradd' command

useradd <username>

3. Now create a special group for that user.

groupadd <groupname>

4. Now to add the user to the group

gpasswd -a <username> <groupname>

5. Change the group ownership of the special directory to that group.

chgrp -R groupname
/path/to/your/web/directory

6. Enable write permissions

chmod -R g+rw
/path/to/your/web/directory
```

And it worked. I was able to add a new user (and I could confirm this by looking at the /etc/passwd file). I then logged out and tried to log in with Cyberduck using the new credentials and setting it to FTP (instead of SSH) and it didn't work. It did however work to log in with SSH with the new user credentials. So it seems I can successfully add a new SSH user but not a new FTP user.

I need the user to be FTP so I can hook WordPress up and begin editing. How do I specific the user to be FTP as opposed to SSH? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer to my question and figured I'd document here for anyone else who runs across this issue. It's surprisingly easy.

Just go to this link and download the plug-in:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/ssh-sftp-updater-support/

You obviously have to upload this straight into your WordPress directory in the SFTP (/wp-content/plugins) in order for it to work correctly since it won't work from within the WordPress dashboard.

Once those files are there, when WordPress prompts you to login to your 'FTP' it will have an option for SSH which you can select and log-in. Voila!